# Ag grid is not showing as intended

Tags: angular, ag-grid, web-frontend, ag-grid-angular, angular-grid

component.html-->

[component.html screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDncp.jpg)

component.ts-->
[ts screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZj4z.jpg)

component.css-->

`@import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css'; /* Quartz Theme Specific CSS */ @import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css';`

## [image screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HjIj.png)

I was expecting a tabular form of data representation but all I got was this....Any suggestions..?